# How to use multiple adapters with OpenVPN and force certain apps to use certain adapters?

Tags: vpn, ip, openvpn

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 box. I have OpenVPN installed and I use it to connect to my VPN service.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple network interfaces/adapters so that I can have certain programs using the VPN and certain applications using my normal ISP connection. Is this possible?

My research points me to using the TAP adapters that can be installed after installing OpenVPN. I have created a TAP adapter using the "Add new TAP virtual ethernet adapter" .bat script that came with OpenVPN.

So now I have 1 physical adapter and 1 TAP adapter. I have also found this software called ForceBindIP.exe which supposedly forces certain apps to use certain IPs/adapters.

As a test I connected to the VPN. This gave the TAP adapter an IP address of `10.2.10.4`. If I use Google Chrome and find my pubic IP, it gives me something like `176.211.x.x`.

Next I ran ForceBindIp on my local firefox.exe and told it to use the IP address of my physical network adapter (`192.168.0.4`). So now I start up Firefox and search for my public IP and it also show my IP as `176.211.x.x`.

So both Chrome and Firefox are apparently still using the same adapter? What am I doing wrong here? Is it even possible to do what I am attempting? Ideally I just want to be able to define which programs use which adapters (and thus controlling which public IP address they have).